# Convert hyperlinks into footnotes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I currently employ a VBA script to copy all the hyperlinks in an MS Word document and list them in a new document. However, I wonder if there is any way to update this VBA script such that it would translate those hyperlinks into footnotes without affecting the original display words --or live hyperlinks, for that matter. This would be really helpful as copying and pasting those hyperlinks back into the original document is very, very time-consuming. The VBA script I currently have:

```
Sub PullHyperlinks()
    Dim Src As Document
    Dim Link As Hyperlink
    Dim iDoDisplay As Integer

    Set Src = ActiveDocument
    If Src.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
        iDoDisplay = MsgBox("Include display text for links?", vbYesNo)

        Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
        For Each Link In Src.Hyperlinks
            If iDoDisplay = vbYes Then
                Selection.TypeText Link.TextToDisplay
                Selection.TypeText vbTab
            End If
            Selection.TypeText Link.Address
            Selection.TypeParagraph
        Next Link
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no hyperlinks in this document."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: More info on how to access header/footer can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.headersfooters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, FtNt As Footnote
With ActiveDocument
  For i = .Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Rng = .Hyperlinks(i).Range
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Set FtNt = .Footnotes.Add(Rng)
    FtNt.Range.FormattedText = .Hyperlinks(i).Range.FormattedText
    .Hyperlinks(i).Range.Delete
    With FtNt.Range.Hyperlinks(1)
      .TextToDisplay = .Address
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you soo much! Is there any way to change display texts into urls afterwards with wdFootnotesStory ?

Comment: This is a very powerful script! So helpful! Thank you sooo much!

PS: Oh, for my use, I just tweaked a few thing --deleted the     ".Hyperlinks(i).Range.Delete" line. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I thought the intention was to *move* the hyperlink to the footnote.